# In Linux is there a way to be know when a thread has completed without using a polling / pthread_join mechanism?

Tags: linux, multithreading

Is it possible to wait on some fd or pthread_t and know if a thread has completed ? I am mainly looking for some mechanism similar to the select call where we know that a socket is triggered.

I am coding out a producer-consumer problem for practice and wanted to have a clean way of knowing when some worker thread has completed rather than waiting on each thread with a pthread_join.

I can use some sort of shared memory datastructure / IPC / synchronization mechanism but want to know if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: I prefer [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to `select` (but both are multiplexing syscalls). You may want to learn more about [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) and use mutexes and condition variables. You'll use some condition variable to signal that a given state has been reached...

Comment: You can always create a pipe/socketpair and write to it on thread end.

Comment: @ninjalj: I know there are such synchronization mechanisms but I don't want to know if that's the common design. It seems a contorted way of doing things.

Comment: I would go with the pipe only if you are already `select()/poll()`ing for other events, so as to integrate the wait with your main loop (this trick is used a lot to convert signals into pollable events). Otherwise, condition variables are pretty standard.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Why not make that comment an answer? :)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: condition variables have a blocking wait (pthread_cond_wait). Is there a way to get a non-blocking check ?

Comment: `pthread_cond_timedwait` could be useful....